# Is it possible to run an Outlook macro when a new Contact is created/saved?

Tags: vba, outlook, macros

I have an Outlook macro that edits certain fields in all of my Contacts.  Is it possible to auto-trigger this macro to run whenever a new Contact is created/saved?

Comment: [Outlook: Items.ItemAdd event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869609.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this code to the `ThisOutlookSession` module:

```
Private WithEvents objNewContact As Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Set objNewContact = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts).Items
End Sub

Private Sub objNewContact_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    MsgBox Item.CompanyAndFullName & " added"
End Sub

Private Sub objNewContact_ItemChange(ByVal Item As Object)
    MsgBox Item.CompanyAndFullName & " changed"
End Sub
```

`Application_StartUp` will set objNewContact to watch the contacts folder when you start Outlook.
`ItemAdd` will fire when you save the contact.
`ItemChange` will fire when you save an existing contact after changing it.

As the link provided by @Maciej states - **The sample code must be placed in a class module** and ThisOutlookSession is a class module.

Comment: Thank you very much.  Was able to get it working by copying/pasting my existing macro into the body of ItemAdd.  Out of curiosity - could I have called the macro, which was located in Module1, from inside ItemAdd, instead of moving it to ThisOutlookSession?

Comment: Yes you could - as long as it's defined as `Public` rather than `Private`.  In my example you would just replace the `MsgBox` line with something like `NameOfYourMacro Item` or `Call NameOfYourMacro(Item)`